# New NIC device naming in 12.10?

Tags: kernel, devices, device-name

I've just discovered after installing Ubuntu 12.10 that there seems to be new device names for eth0...ethX.

However, I haven't managed to find any documentation that explains the new naming convention in Ubuntu.  Can someone explain what p25p1 actually means and what advantages it has over eth0..ethX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer.  I'm surprised no one else answered this question.

It would appear to be a function of the newer kernels and is called [Consistent Network Device Naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming)

The new naming scheme is:

**Lan-On-Motherboard interfaces**

> em<port number>_< virtual function instance / NPAR Index> (ethernet-on-motherboard <1,2 ..>)

**PCI add-in interfaces**

> p<slot number>p<port number>_<virtual function instance / NPAR Index>

Other Linux conventions, such as . and : suffixes remain unchanged and are still applicable